# How to wait until tasks 'Result' property has an actual result

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, task

I have an array of tasks, after I receive those tasks I use

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(TasksList.ToArray(), CompleteTasks);
```

where CompleteTasks() is a method in which I use after all tasks should finish computing their results. This works the first time around, however when I go through it again some Tasks results property says 'Not yet Computed' and it still goes through my CompleteTasks method. What is the best way to handle this issue?

Here is the complete code below:

```
public Checker(IEnumerable<Website> websites)
    {
        WebsiteHelper.Websites = websites.ToList<Website>();
        Check(WebsiteHelper.Websites);

    }

public void Check(IList<Website> tempWeb)
    {
        int mySiteCounter = 0;
        // Go through each website in the list in parallel
        Parallel.ForEach(tempWeb, web =>
        {
            TempWebResult.Add(new WebsiteResult { });
            try
            {

                StartingTime = DateTime.Now;
                PageCheck(web, mySiteCounter++);
                EndingTime = DateTime.Now;

            }
            //write the Message to a log
            //Catch Exceptions

             });

        CheckNewResult();
    }

public void PageCheck(Website webParam, int mySiteCounter)
    {
        TempCounter = mySiteCounter;
        TempURL = webParam.SiteUrl;
        Uri uri = new Uri(TempURL);
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        myReq.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get; // Used to contact the Internet resource


        try
        {

            myReq.KeepAlive = false;
            myReq.Timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000; //set to 10 minutes

            var checkResult = TempWebResult.ElementAt(mySiteCounter);


            //Use .FromAsync to start asynchronous operation request and to return the actual web response
            try
            {
                checkResult.RequestSentTime = DateTime.Now;
                Stopwatch WatchTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                Task<WebResponse> task = Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(
                    myReq.BeginGetResponse,
                    myReq.EndGetResponse,
                    null);

                //Add a task to the task list
                TempTasksList.Add(task);



                Console.WriteLine(mySiteCounter + ": Url to check: " + myReq.RequestUri);

                //Continue after request and response have been made
                task.ContinueWith(t =>
                    {


                        var responseCode = (HttpWebResponse)t.Result;
                        WatchTimer.Stop();
                        checkResult.milli = WatchTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                        checkResult.ResponseReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;
                        //diff = checkResult.ResponseReceivedTime - checkResult.RequestSentTime;
                        //checkResult.milli = (int)diff.TotalMilliseconds;

                        checkResult.Url = webParam.SiteUrl;
                        checkResult.SystemStatus = "Up";
                        webParam.SiteStatus = checkResult.SystemStatus;
                        checkResult.SystemId = mySiteCounter + "-" + myReq.RequestUri.ToString();


                        Console.WriteLine(mySiteCounter + "Url that came back: " + responseCode.ResponseUri);

                        ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result);

                        if (responseCode.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) // Checks if status is OK or not
                        {

                            checkResult.ResponseStatus = responseCode.StatusCode.ToString();
                            checkResult.ResponseStatusCode = "Up";
                            checkResult.SystemStatus = "Up";
                            webParam.SiteStatus = checkResult.SystemStatus;
                            checkResult.StatusFlag = true;
                            //Return the Response Url
                            checkResult.ResponseUrl = responseCode.ResponseUri.ToString();
                        }


                        if (checkResult.SystemName == null)
                            checkResult.SystemName = "";
                        if (checkResult.Message == null)
                            checkResult.Message = "";
                        if (checkResult.ResponseUrl == null)
                            checkResult.ResponseUrl = "";


                    });
                task.ContinueWith((t) =>
                    {
                        WatchTimer.Stop();
                        checkResult.milli = WatchTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                        ErrorMessage = GetException(t.Exception);
                        checkResult.ResponseReceivedTime = DateTime.Now;
                       // diff = checkResult.ResponseReceivedTime - checkResult.RequestSentTime;
                       // checkResult.milli = (int)diff.TotalMilliseconds;
                        Console.WriteLine("Status Not Ok");
                        checkResult.SystemId = mySiteCounter + "-" + myReq.RequestUri.ToString();
                        checkResult.ResponseStatus = ErrorMessage;
                        checkResult.ResponseStatusCode = "Down";
                        checkResult.SystemStatus = "Down";
                        webParam.SiteStatus = checkResult.SystemStatus;
                        checkResult.StatusFlag = false;
                    },
                    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

            }
             //Exceptions caught

                       }
        //Exceptions caught
    }


/// <summary>
    /// This method converts the TasksList into an array
    /// and calls the Complete Tasks method
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckNewResult()
    {

        Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(TempTasksList.ToArray(), CompleteTasks);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method waits until all tasks have ran to
    /// completion so it can print results
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tasks"> Array of completed tasks</param>
    private void CompleteTasks(Task[] tasks)
    {

        WebsiteHelper.myLog.Info("***********************************************************");
        WebsiteHelper.myLog.Info("ready to print check results now");

        //Wait until all tasks have ran to completion

        if (tasks.Any(t => t.Status == (TaskStatus.RanToCompletion) || t.Status == (TaskStatus.Faulted)))
        {


            Parallel.ForEach(TempWebResult, result =>
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(result);
                // Console.WriteLine("new line");

                WebsiteHelper.myLog.Info(result.SQL);

            });
        }

        if(DownSitesHandler.FirstTime == true)
        {
            DownSitesHandler.FirstTime = false;
            CheckDownSites();
            if (WebsiteHelper.Self().HasDownSite == true)
                ReCheck();


        }

        Console.WriteLine("done printing all results");
    }

/// <summary>
    /// This method rechecks all down websites
    /// </summary>
    public void ReCheck()
    {

        //Checker newCheckerObject = new Checker(downsites);
        WebsiteHelper.myLog.Info(DateTime.Now + " -- Begin to re-check down sites ");
        IList<Website> temporaryWebList = DownSitesHandler.downsites.ToList<Website>();
        Check(temporaryWebList);
        //newCheckerObject.SendRequest();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you running continueWhenAll on tasks that have already completed to run?

Comment: @omerschleifer I use it because I want to make sure all tasks are completed before I call the CompleteTasks method I created. Once the array is passed in sometimes not all tasks in that array is completed just yet.

Comment: I understand why you are calling ContinueWhenAll. but after that is done, why are you calling it a second time?

Comment: @omerschleifer It is because I am sending url requests over the network and I am keeping track of websites that are down. So after the initial check I recheck using a new array using just the down websites to see if it is still down using the same method as before part of which is the .continuewhenall method.

Comment: Are you creating new Tasks in your second pass or are you trying to reuse the Task instance that told you the website was down in the first place?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I am creating new Tasks .

Comment: `CompleteTasks` will execute only after all tasks you passed to `ContinueWhenAll()` complete. If it looks like that's not happening for you, you need to include actual code that we can run to see this.

Comment: @svick Code is now shown above

Comment: @PrestonGuillot Code is now shown above

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I was able to handle the problem. Before the re-check I called the Thread.Sleep method to give the system time to complete, which allowed all the results to come in smoothly.

Comment: This is a very brittle solution.  You are "giving the system time to complete" - how much time?  what if it took longer?  You should consider rewriting your implementation to work with continuations, and also use the overloaded Parallel.ForEach that gives you access to a thread safe index for each item in the loop

Comment: Install your code on a faster machine and you'll see what @Baldy is talking about.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't comb through all of your code, but it doesn't seem like you're using continuations correctly. The continuation is itself a separate task, and at some point, you will need to wait for that to finish as well. For example:

```
var first = Task.Run(() => { Console.Write("First"); });
var second = first.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("Second"));
second.Wait();
```

If you waited only for "first", there's no guarantee the continuation has finished yet. Same goes for the ContinueWhenAll method, that returns a task you need to wait for.

Also, adding multiple continuations to the same task does not imply any sort of precedence relation between the two. After the antecedent task finishes, they may be started in any order, run in parallel, whatever. For example:

```
var taskA = Task.Run(() => { Console.Write("A"); });
var taskB1 = taskA.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("B1"));
var taskB2 = taskA.ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine("B2"));
var bothFinished = Task.WhenAll(taskB1, taskB2);
bothFinished.Wait();
```

Here, you might see B1 and B2 printed in any order, and you'll need to wait for both to finish if you want to ensure they've run.

That may or may not be the solution to all your problems, but it should be start.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening is that your Tasks havent finished their job yet.

Solution 1: Use `Task.WaitAll(tasks);` This will wait for all remaining Tasks to end;

Solution 2 : Use something like this :

```
            var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
                        tasks,
                        (antecedents) =>
                        {
                            //Do Some Work Here
                        });
            continuation.Wait();
```

Hope that helps.